# Loop in IndexedDB Transactions

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, loops, indexeddb

I am using the product design tool "Lumise" which saves the guest designs and uploads in IndexedDB. I want to save the data which is saved in these object stores in MySQL table using the insert query. I have created a selectindexeddb.js file and indexeddbtomysql.php file and already there is a file for the tool which created the IndexedDB and updating it called "app-uncompressed.js".

my question is: I want to make the loop for each transaction happen to the design from creating, update or delete how can I do it from separate js file.

hint: I have tried to write this for loop in lumise js file but it shows bunch of errors also because this file is extremely huge. 
any help ?

app-uncompressed.js :)

> https://pastebin.com/cm6aNZ2A

Another Hint:)

in this file, you can focus in 12177 lines which starts creating IndexedDB

**selectindexeddb.js**

```
var db;
var request = indexedDB.open("lumise");
var transaction = db.transaction(["designs"]);
var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("designs");
var request = objectStore.get("K730MRT0"); // this i want it to have it from app_uncompressed.js as a  variable.                              
 // i want to make the loop here ?!

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
// Do something with the request.result!
var designid = request.result.id;
var designname = request.result.name;
var designscreenshot = request.result.screenshot;
console.log("rsults is " + designid);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'indexeddbtomysql.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {design_id:designid ,design_name:designname,design_screenshot:designscreenshot },
            success: function(data) {
                alert("saved y marweta ;)")
            }
        });
   };
```

**indexeddbtomysql.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../config.php';


$design_id = $_POST['design_id'];
$design_name = $_POST['design_name'];
$design_screenshot = $_POST['design_screenshot'];

$query = 'INSERT INTO `user_designs`( `key`, `name`, `screnshot`) VALUES ($design_id   
,$design_name , $design_screenshot);';

  ?>
```

updated I have tried to put the for loop in the `app_uncompersed.js`  but it didn`t work

```
        save : function(ob, storeName, callback) {

            if (this.db == null)
                return callback(null);
                var i ;
             for (i = 0; i < count(rows); i++) {


            var trans = this.db.transaction(ob.length === 2 ?
            [storeName, 'dumb'] : [storeName], "readwrite");
            var store = trans.objectStore(storeName);

            if (ob.id === null || ob.id === undefined)
                ob.id = parseInt(newDate().getTime()/1000)
                .toString(36)+':'+Math.random().toString(36).substr(
                  2);

            var obj = $.extend({
                    created: new Date().getTime()
                }, (ob[0] !== undefined ? ob[0] : ob));

            var process = store.put(obj, obj.id);

            if (typeof callback == 'function')
                process.onsuccess = callback;
                console.log("ABC");

            if (ob[1] !== undefined) {

                var obj_dumb = $.extend({
                    id: obj.id,
                    created: obj.created
                }, ob[1]);

                trans.objectStore('dumb').put(obj_dumb, obj.id);

            }
                    var designid = obj.id; //this var i want to save  
          }
        },
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? That might create some more context. This is a very dense problem right now, and not well-defined.

Comment: my question is  that i have data stored in indexed dp by design tool i use, all i want to do that with every transaction like create, update and delete in these three functions i want make for loop for each record to update it in mysql but not from the tool js file because it is dum so i created another file and i am trying to access the indexed dp from it , BTW i will update my question thanks for the comment

Comment: are you referring to indexeddb or indexed dp? can you clarify what is indexed dp?

Comment: IndexedDB you can know more about it through this link --> (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently learning IndexedDB and find this link to be very useful. There is a tutorial in it which covers what you're trying to achieve.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Comment: I have already checked this link before but i cant find what i am looking for on  it , Thank you btw.